# Changing the folder in Git Desktop

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to change the folder where Git Desktop saves the files it takes from github.com?

I want it to save in the wamp www folder so that I can edit it in Visual Code and then push it to github.

Answer (score 6):

In GitHub Desktop 1.3.2 `File > Clone Repository` gives an option to select the path -- at least on a per repository basis.

[image]

I'm not sure if there is a more general way to choose the `default` repo path.

Comment: Thanks.. just what i need it

Comment: Thanks Mike Atkisson

Answer (score 5):

The easy solution is to move the directory to another location and git desktop will auto prompt you to locate it!

[image: Git Desktop]